# Store images in a plist

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, pdf, plist

I obtain seven thumbnail images from my one PDF melodramatically, and these seven images are stored in one array as objects. Now i want to show the images in the array in a `UIWebView`, but it is not possible because the web view needs a path to a resource or a plist path. So I want to store these images in a plist; how can I do this?
In my array, only the image objects are available, not the names, and all seven images are not static images.

I am new in iPhone programming, so please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Do you want to store images in a .plist or display images in a UIWebView? Because your question has already included a possible solution. Please edit your question subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not make much sense to me (melodramatically?). Contrary to what you believe, `UIWebView` cannot deal with a property list. What would it be supposed to do with it? A web view can display data from a URL request, a string of HTML or a bunch of data in a specified format.

In your case, the latter would apply: convert one of your images into an `NSData` object (with `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`) and pass it to the web view with `-loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`.

If you want to display all images at once, you would have to save the images to disk and generate appropriate HTML code.

Comment: ya i do the same way but image will not be display